# Does "background-size:"css style work in all browser (CSS)?

Tags: html, css, w3c

I have this simple css:

```
.privateMessageNumber{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;  
    font-size: large;
    background-image:url('/images/icon/mail.png');
    background-size: 37px 25px;
}
```

the question is will this css work in all browsers? I heard css2 didn't accept `background-size`, but what does that mean?

Does that mean that if user runs on browser that only support css2 then we can't use:

```
    background-size: 37px 25px;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at 'Can I Use' whenever you're unsure if a property will work in the browsers you're supporting.

http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers have supported background-size for many moons but IE only since version 9.

Answer (score 0):

[No](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Browser_compatibility)

The Mozilla Developer Network is another good reference for compatibility.